# Backbone: Triggering another div to show

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Let me start off with, I'm brand spanking new to Backbone. What I need to do is super simple. I need to hover over a btn, which in turn shows a previously hidden DIV. There are multiple buttons and divs with identical classes, so currentTarget is a must.

Here's the event:

```
'mouseenter .share-btn' : 'shareShow',
```

Here's the function:

```
        'shareShow' : function (e){
        var $targetedTools = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.share-tools');
        $targetedTools.show();
    },
```

The problem is that the .share-tools are not showing.

Thanks for taking the time to help, and take it easy on me ... I gave this my best shot :)

Comment: is `shareShow()` being called or not?

Comment: It logs out if I console.log at the end of the function, is that what you mean?

Comment: set a breakpoint in the function and step through it. that'll show the error pretty easily I suspect

Comment: here's the markup :http://jsfiddle.net/jU34g/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was jquery related, specifically traversing the DOM. I needed to find the closest parent of ".tile" and from there find the class of ".share-tools".

```
        'shareShow' : function (e){
            $(e.currentTarget).closest('.tile').find('.share-tools').fadeIn('fast');
        },
```